# Bash: execute in parallel some processes but wait the slowest

Tags: linux, bash, multi-core, parallel-processing, multi-threaded

Hello I'm writing a bash script where I have to restore around 8+ big sets of ip with ipset-restore command.

Actually my shell script basically has a list like

ipset-restore < list1.txt
ipset-restore < list2.txt
ipset-restore < list3.txt
...

doing it in this way is pretty slow and because machine has resources and ipset is multhitreaded and can perform various operations in parallel I would like to cast many ipset-restore at once.

I tought of using **nohup** however doing it this way would make me being unable to see if the processes have finished before carry out new instructions.

I need that every process have finished before proceeding next.

(basically I need to wait for the slowest before proceeding).

Bonus: it exists a linux package to do so with also monitoring the resources so that spawn of processes is handled automatically without hugging all the resources?

Comment: Aren't "I would like to cast many `ipset-restore` at once" and "I need that every process have finished before proceeding next" contradictory.

Comment: I mean, I want to launch many processes at once instead doing one by one but also wait that them have completed before continue the script otherwise I would have ipset still filling while the rest of the script would continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have all the jobs running in parallel, you should have run them
as background jobs, while the main script continues on creating
them all. This is done with a command like:

```
process &
```

For more information see
[Running Linux Commands in Background and Foreground](https://linuxhandbook.com/run-process-background/).

Once all the commands were issued and are running in the
background, you may wait for all of them to finish by using the
the [wait command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wait.1p.html),
which is described as:

> If the wait utility is invoked with no operands, it shall wait
> until all process IDs known to the invoking shell have terminated
> and exit with a zero exit status.

If you run into problems with it waiting for too many processes,
you could use a solution that keeps the PIDs of the started
processes and waits for them only.
See the post
[How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish, and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0).